# Import legacy data to SAP CRM 7.0

Tags: sap-crm

Hello I would like some advice, links, etc., on importing legacy data from an external system to SAP CRM 7.0.

We are currently using a different SQL based CRM system and are moving to SAP CRM 7.0.  I need to export all the SQL database data and feed it into SAP CRM 7.0.  What tools are available to me or what can I do to accomplish this task.

I am very new to SAP CRM 7 and SAP in general.  I guess you can assume that the data will be a text file (maybe a CSV).  How will I handle 1->many relationships?  etc...

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the data will be several CSV files - one per source table. I don't know a lot about CRM, but you might want to take a look at the [Legacy System Migration Workbench](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/ad/2d54a41d7011d2b42e006094b944c8/frameset.htm) - a great tool for importing data into SAP R/3 based systems. I assume you already know the docs at http://help.sap.com/crm. There are also some [best practices documents](http://help.sap.com/bp_crm70/CRM_DE/HTML/index.htm) available (navigate to Implementation Project --> Data Migration) - but you'll need a SAPnet Service Marketplace user ID (S.....) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your options may vary depending on what licenses or tools you have at fingertips or what backend is behind your legacy CRM, but generally SAP recommends for interchanging data between CRM and external systems [SAP CRM Integration services](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/08/90e753b884424de10000000a174cb4/frameset.htm) which has [several adapters](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/07/19e8532a84424de10000000a174cb4/frameset.htm) for different data types.

SAP MDG is a more full-fledged solution, equipped [with more tools](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_mdg80/8.0.5/en-US/f8/0d845270a9836ae10000000a423f68/frameset.htm). Also CRM has industry specific tools, for example, [for utilities](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm700_ehp02/helpdata/en/bc/22a4535ed6461b95d0a3a0ec3bb270/frameset.htm).

Also check [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57663848/911419) that was written for MSSQL database, but it is fully relevant for any DB.