# SAP SLT to Kafka integration?

Tags: apache-kafka, slt

I need to capture CDC data for selected tables and columns from SAP ECC to Kafka topics.

There is currently SAP SLT layer which sends data from SAP to non-SAP systems. Can we utilize SAP SLT to send data to Kafka Topics or do we need to utilize any other connector. I know there is [ODP](https://www.confluent.io/hub/init/kafka-connect-odp) connector which is available to extract data directly from SAP ECC, I need to utilize existing SLT layer and need to confirm if it can be utilized to send CDC data to Kafka topics without a need to any other connectors.

Any references would be helpful.

Comment: You can create your own ABAP BADI's/SDK and write the data from SLT to any target system: Check sap note: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2652704

Answer (score 0):

> Can we utilize SAP SLT to send data to Kafka Topics

No.

As per my knowledge only SAP BODS has Kafka Connector [since version 4.2](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/03/new-feature-of-bods-42-and-bods-41/).

All the rest integration tools including SLT have CDC functionality but support only RDBMS target, look at this comparison overview

[image]

Check also my answer here: [What is the best way to transfer data from SAP to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57663848/911419)

Comment: I have come across this help page in SAP where it mentions transfer of data to Kafka using SLT. https://help.sap.com/viewer/4e46a41a609447418edade2ddc8d2442/2.7.latest/en-US/aef3e6be31204adf8f8fd7d69adcc8a5.html . Though not much details.

Comment: in this help page they describe DataHub scenario where SLT is a source and Kafka is a target, I wrote about DataHub in the answer I linked, it is a separate SAP product. Having only SLT is not sufficient to implement this scenario